# Rpi pico zero W - display script not errors

Tags: display, pi-pico, micropython

I am a beginner with electronics and coding, trying to get an OLED display with ssd1306 to work with my Rpi Pico W. I have connected the display's SDA and SCL to GP2 and GP3.

When trying to run the following code, also using the micropython_ssd1306-03 package:

```
from machine import Pin, I2C
from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C
from oled import Write, GFX, SSD1306_I2C
from oled.fonts import ubuntu_mono_15, ubuntu_mono_20
import utime

WIDTH =128
HEIGHT= 32

i2c=I2C(1,scl=Pin(3),sda=Pin(2),freq=200000)

oled = SSD1306_I2C(WIDTH,HEIGHT,i2c)

write15 = Write(oled, ubuntu_mono_15)
write20 = Write(oled, ubuntu_mono_20)
write20.text("OLED", 0, 0)
write15.text("Display", 0, 20)

oled.text("Hello World", 0, 40)
oled.show()
```

I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 20, in <module>
  File "/lib/oled/ssd1306.py", line 127, in __init__
  File "/lib/oled/ssd1306.py", line 47, in __init__
  File "/lib/oled/ssd1306.py", line 72, in init_display
  File "/lib/oled/ssd1306.py", line 132, in write_cmd
OSError: [Errno 5] EIO
```

Is my display broken? It is detected when I use i2c.scan() but seemingly won't initialize.

Comment: I assume you have 3.3V out and Gnd connected also? Why are you importing SSD1306_I2C from 2 files?

Comment: Should it not be =I2C(0, not =I2C(1, ?

Comment: It might be helpful to provide a wiring diagram.